# TypeError: browser.webRequest.onHeaderReceived is undefined

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I have this simple example for a webextension that tries to capture the server response headers. 
When I debug it, it loads in the browser. But the web console logs this error instead of the site header:

> response header: [object Object],[object Object],[object
>   Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object
>   Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object
>   Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object
>   Object],[object Object],[object Object]

The script file: `background.js`:

```
function logHeader(requestDetails){
  console.log("respons header: " + requestDetails.responseHeaders);
  return {responseHeaders: requestDetails.responseHeaders};
}

browser.webRequest.onHeaderReceived.addListener(
  logHeader,
  {urls: ["<all_urls>"]},
  ["blocking","responseHeaders"]
);
```

The manifest file: `manifest.jso`

```
{
  "description": "Demonstrating Response Header",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "testWebExtResponseHeader",
  "version": "1.0",

  "permissions": [
    "webRequest",
    "<all_urls>",
    "webRequestBlocking"
  ],

  "background":{
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  }
}
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Use JSON.stringify or something similar to log the object as string.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that the thing you're trying to `console.log` an array of objects :

> **webRequest.HttpHeaders** : An array of HTTP headers. Each header is represented as an object with two properties: name and either value or binaryValue.
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest/HttpHeaders

And since you're doing a concatenation inside your `console.log`, Javascript tries to convert the `requestDetails.responseHeaders` to a string, which results in an array of `[object Object]` strings (since `anyObject.toString()` returns the `[object Object]` string).

---

### 1. Stringify the array first

Simplest solution is to first transform the object you're trying to log (here, your `request.responseHeaders` array of objects) to a readable string using `JSON.stringify`:

```
console.log("response header: " + JSON.stringify(requestDetails.responseHeaders));
```

which would give you the expected result:

```
response header: [{"name":"date","value":"Tue, 13 Mar 2018 20:41:35 GMT"},{ ........
```

### 2. Log only the array (without concatenation)

You could also `console.log(requestDetails.responseHeaders)` directly, which should result in a correctly formated and interactive array of results (here, result in Firefox 61) :

[image: Firefox 61 - console.log interactive]